# Restart only the Windows OS (not the whole computer) via .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows, restart

I know that it's possible to manually restart only Windows by holding down the Shift key, clicking restart and then the OK button, but is there a way to do this programatically in a .NET app?

Comment: Restart the OS but not the computer? What does that even mean?

Comment: Presumably it means that after unmounting filesystems and unloading drivers, the OS finishes execution with a jump to its own entry point, not the firmware entrypoint (power-on interrupt handler).

Comment: @JesusRamos see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/143272

Comment: @mikez Applies to Windows 95?

Comment: @Mike: "Applies to: Windows 95"  Did portions of the MS-DOS startup still run during boot in those days?

Comment: you could execute shutdown /r /t 0 ?

Comment: @JesusRamos Yup quite old. There's no way anyone is running a .NET app on a system that supports it.

Comment: Why do you even want this?

Answer (score 8):

I assume you're referring to [this microsoft knowledgebase article about restarting windows without restarting the PC](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/143272) - which is also [referenced here on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_key) ?

You'll note that this refers only to windows 95, 98 and ME. It makes sense in that context, as those versions of windows ran on top of MS-DOS, and so I'm assuming that it restarted the windows layer without restarting the DOS layer underneath it.

On later versions of windows, holding the shift key will have no effect, as they don't run on top of DOS. Restarting windows *is* restarting the whole computer, as there's no "layer underneath it". If you're still using windows 95, 98 or ME... umm... good luck and have a nice life?